# Require WordPress Login only for posts, not pages?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to create a WordPress site with a login system, but I only want the login to be required to view POSTS. They should be able to view pages without logging in. I did some research, but no one had exactly what I was looking for, so I tried to puzzle something together, and this is what I came up with, but it doesn't work.

```
function my_force_login() {
    global $post;
        if ( ( is_single() && !is_user_logged_in() ) ){ 
            auth_redirect(); 
        }    
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Set posts visibility to *private* by default?
Your function should work though, how do you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, but it has run on the [correct point](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect):

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() 
{
    global $post; // Use this to detect the custom post types if needed
    if ( ( is_single() && !is_user_logged_in() ) )
    { 
        auth_redirect(); 
    }    
});
```

Comment: I thought the function was fine! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

add it to your single.php

```
<?php auth_redirect(); ?>
```

This function will check if the user is logged in and if he is not it will redirect him to the login page http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/auth_redirect

Comment: keep in mind that `single.php` is used by posts as well as custom post types. if you want to just redirect blog posts, you'll need to explicitly test for that.

Answer (score 0):

Details of the post is being displayed in the single.php. Please put the code of displaying post's content into the condition. Then you will get the solution. Try the following code into the single.php in the twentyforteen theme.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
   get_template_part( 'content', 'single' );
}
```

Now get logged out and refresh the browser, you can see none of content are shown.